# How to escape message System.Int32 in C#

Tags: c#

I'm just beginning to learn C# so I have a question.

Why do I get the message `System.Int 32[]` ?

```
public static int[] GetFirstEvenNumbers(int count)
{
    int[] array = new int[count];

    for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++)
        array[i - 1] = i * 2; 

    for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
        Console.Write(array[j] + " ");                        

    return new int[count];         
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.Write(GetFirstEvenNumbers(5));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Because when you call Console.Write with a value that is not a string, the default behaviour is to output the type of the value.

Comment: You may use Console.Write(string.Join(", ", GetFirstEvenNumbers(5)));

Comment: return new int[count]; should be: return array;

Comment: Because no compiler/runtime yet built (or ever to be built) is able to take `print(something)` and correctly infer what *you want* to see. There will be defaults, but no magic

Answer (score 1):

What you `Write` to the console has type `int[]`. This type, `int[]`, does not override `ToString()`. Therefore the behavior it inherits from `object` is used, and that is to simply return the full name of its type, which is `System.Int32[]`.

What you want to do is create a `string` consisting of all the entries in the array, separated with some symbol. You can use `string.Join` for that. For example:

```
var firstFiveEven = GetFirstEvenNumbers(5);
var firstFiveEvenAsStringWithSeparators = string.Join(" - ", firstFiveEven);
Console.Write(firstFiveEvenAsStringWithSeparators);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the bahaviour you see is because when you pass an object (regardless of type) to the Console.Write method then it will call the objects ToString() method. 
Some types have overridden this method in order to present the object or value in a way that makes sense for the type (for example, an integer would print its value).

Many objects have not overriden this method and thus they default back to Object.ToString() and the behaviour of Object.ToString() is to print out the type of the object.

You can read more about it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0):

what Stuartd said is true:
in your code assuming you want to write each integer of the array and then all the array 
in one time there is some changes need to be done to your code

1- returning new empty array or array of zeros in your method  GetFirstEvenNumbers need to be replaced by the array variable from your code which hold the multiplied by two values.

2- since your method(function) return array of int then you need to convert that to string so that it could be written by the console a good c# method to use is string.join
so your code after these changes should look something like this:

```
    public static int[] GetFirstEvenNumbers(int count)
    {
        int[] array = new int[count];

        for (int i = 1; i <= array.Length; i++)
            array[i - 1] = i * 2;
        // if you don't need to repeat the result twice get rid off the 
        // second for loop and Console.Write
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++)
            Console.Write(array[j] + " ");

        return array;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Join(",",GetFirstEvenNumbers(5)));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

I hope this helps.